# View Pager with ExecuteTask

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-designer

I have a AsyncTask to get the web service data through JSON. I would like to have these items on pages with ViewPager and textsViews. My problem is how to do this without fragments, want it to be dynamic.
I do not understand very well where I put the setViewAdapter would be in onPostExecute?
To view the pager follow the following links:

[View Pager Link 1](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ViewPager/MultiView2/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/mvp2/MainActivity.java)

[View Pager Link 2](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

I'm having trouble aligning these two things. Please help me!! Maybe my question was not clear.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What's problem while using fragments? They are just elements of ViewPager. So, create fragment which is consisted of textview(s).

To reload ViewPager use `yourpager.setAdapter(adapter)` inside `onPostExecute()` block.

That is , pipeline:

1. initialize ViewPager
2. Download data
3. Reload ViewPager's elements.

Comment: I should not create fragments for each of the webservice returns? I do not know how many results it will bring.
I must have misunderstood the concept so ...

Comment: Initialization of viewpager must be made on create the activity?

Comment: Yes. You initialize viewpager in `onCreate()` method, then setup it everytime you want.